# E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)

Tags: tensorflow, chatbot, rasa

I am using rasa 1.9.6 on ubuntu in Vmware I have been getting this error in both training as well as running the model. It allows training the model but I am unable to run it I need to run my Bot can someone please help

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with specifics about the command you ran, your config.yml, and the exact error message you got. Since you're new on stackoverflow, I'd highly recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, as the guidelines will help you get better answers

Answer (score 1):

According to [rasa forum](https://forum.rasa.com/t/tensorflow-driver-unknown-error-303/21661/27), the origin of this issue is due to tensorflow and graphics card configuration. GPU’s do not typically provide an advantage for the Rasa models. This can be safely ignored

Installing nvidia-modprobe can solve this issue.

```
sudo apt install nvidia-modprobe
```

Other solutions you can try are :

- Uninstall and install CUDA and cuDNN.
- Install tensorflow-gpu.
- Uninstall and install different Nvidia driver versions.

The problem also could be that only some `/dev/nvidia*` files are present before running Python with sudo, check using `$ ls /dev/nvidia*`, after running the [Device Node verification script](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#runfile-verifications) the `/dev/nvidia-uvm` file gets added.